# SQL query to get the below output

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Need help for query:

```
Id  Name  Balance
1   A     10
2   A     -10
3   A     10
4   A     15
5   B     10.5
6   B     -10.5
7   B     25
```

Requirement: I want to remove the balance with +ve and –ve values for each name. I am expecting the below output

Expected results: --

```
Id Name Balance
1  A    10
2  A    15
3  B    25
```

Can you please share me SQL query.

Comment: If you are calculating the balance, why are there 2 rows for Name "A". What will happen for a scenario when +ve and -ve values are not same for any Name. Life will be very easy if there is only 1 record per name

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

Create dummy data for testing

```
CREATE TABLE foo (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(50), Balance money);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 'A', 10);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2, 'A', -10);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (3, 'A', 10);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (4, 'A', 15);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (5, 'B', 10.5);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (6, 'B', -10.5);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (7, 'B', 25);
```

1) Create a temp table that has one extra MatchFound column to record whether a match is found.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(Id int, Name varchar(50), Balance decimal(10,2), MatchFound bit);
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Id, Name, Balance, MatchFound)
SELECT Id, Name, Balance, 0
FROM foo;
```

2) Loop through the data to find a match for each row. Update MatchFound column if a match is found.

```
DECLARE @Id INT, @Name VARCHAR(50), @Balance decimal(10,2), @MatchId INT;
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, Name, Balance FROM #TempTable ORDER BY Id;
OPEN MyCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Id, @Name, @Balance

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TempTable WHERE Id = @Id AND MatchFound = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @MatchId = NULL
        SELECT TOP 1 @MatchId = Id FROM #TempTable 
        WHERE Id <> @Id AND Name = @Name AND Balance = @Balance * -1 AND MatchFound = 0
        IF @MatchId IS NOT NULL
            UPDATE #TempTable SET MatchFound = 1 WHERE Id IN (@Id, @MatchId)
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Id, @Name, @Balance
END
CLOSE MyCursor;
DEALLOCATE MyCursor;
```

3) Select and return rows that did not have a match

```
Select Id, Name, Balance From #TempTable Where MatchFound = 0
```

4) Clean up

```
drop table #TempTable
```

Comment: I want to remove the two rows from the main table where sum(balance)=0

Comment: That's quite different than what I thought you asked in your question. Nonetheless. See my updated answer. You might want to update your question to better explain what you are actually asking.

Comment: I am fine with the querry, I am getting performance issues. Is there any way to achive the above logic?